# Deleting messages from SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have one use case where I want to delete some specific messages on the basis of some field from SQS only before processing of the message. I know we can do it by receipt handle only after processing the message. I looked into other aws storage services as well. Can anyone suggest me how to do it and I want to use sqs only?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't use SQS for your use-case?

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone suggest me how to do it and I want to use sqs only?

You **can't do this**. If you require such functionality, SQS is the wrong tool for you. Either you have to implement a custom solution, or find some third party queuing software that will do what you want.